# Centos 'Login incorrect' problem

Tags: linux, centos, login

When I type my username and password into the login field, I receive the following error:

> Login incorrect

How can I solve this problem? I am using CentOS.

Comment: Can you log in as root? If you can't, and you're absolutely sure you typed the username and password correctly, [boot into single user mode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/upgrade-suse-10-3-to-11-3-and-startup-fails/11537#11537), run `openvt -s login`, try to log in, and look in the system logs for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all likelihood you are not giving the right username and password. Are you sure your keyboard layout is the same and you didn't have <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on when you saved your password?